# Spring MVC interceptor - intercept all request

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc

I want to do an interceptor for all requests. The problem is that the interceptor captures the links like `http://localhost:8080/car/cardetails/105303/?currencyCode=USD` , but doesn't captures links like `http://localhost:8080/index.jsp?pageName=oldLegacyPage&currencyCode=USD&locale=en`.

The interceptor is used to translate some legacy links.
I couldn't make it to intercept even request starting with index.jsp

This is the configuration I did in servlet-context.xml (spring version 3.1.1.RELEASE):

```xml
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->
<!-- Controller Mapping Configuration -->
<interceptors>
    <interceptor>
        <mapping path="/**" />
        <beans:bean class="com.mydomain.interceptor.LegacyRequestInterceptor" />
    </interceptor>
</interceptors>

<default-servlet-handler />
```

Thank you

Update:

seems that it works if I modify the servlet mapping from `/` to `/*` of the DispatcherServlet:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and adding the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` bean in servlet-context.xml.

```xml
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
```

Comment: Your interceptor is relative to the path of your `DispatcherServlet`. What is yours mapped to?

Comment: Thank you Sotirios, I tried changing initial from `/` to `/*` but it didn't work without the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping bean. I guess this is the only way to have a working interceptor without declaring a controller or to setup the view resolver to jsp.